# Will Tor keep my info anonymous?

Tags: research

If I use search engines like Google (within Tor) and visit sites that come up in the search results, will those sites know that I visited them? Will they have my IP or personal information? Or will my information be anonymous? I want to protect myself, because in the past, a hacker/troll got my IP. I performed a search for a project I was working on for school. I clicked on the first result and was connected to an IRC channel. The owner of the channel began harassing me and my husband by sending us death threats, all because I accidentally ended up in his chatroom. I don't want this to happen ever again. Will using Tor protect me and my identity from people like this in the future?

I have to add this information in via editing, because I don't have enough points to comment yet. The threats received were via the IRC channel, email and phone. He threatened to kill me and my husband if I ever joined his chatroom again. Then he called my husband's work pretending to be his father. He said that he needed to know my husband's schedule because he was picking him up at work. My husband's father lives across the country. Then the guy emailed me letting me know that he was the one who called my husband's work. We even filed reports with the police and FBI. The police said that they wouldn't actually do anything about it because they had real crimes to deal with like B&E's. These are reasons why I want to be safe online. Will Tor protect my information? If I use a search engine and click on one of the results, will my information be completely anonymous if I visit that site using Tor?

Comment: How was the owner of the chatroom sending threats? While you were in the room, via email, or by some other means?

Comment: In short yes, but I suggest you read https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#AnonymityAndSecurity

Answer (score 1):

Tor will hide your IP address from the sites you visit.

Google will know what *someone* searched for and which results they clicked on. But your IP address is hidden.

The sites you visit via Google search results will know that *someone* came from a Google search and what the search was. But your IP address is hidden.

If your search is fairly unique, and you've dome the same search 'unprotected' in the past, they might be able to correlate.
Tor will not help you if your computer is compromised.